# QueryString Javascript collection object capable of handling arrays

Tags: javascript, parsing, collections, query-string, querystringparameter

I need to take a query string (example: `?name=value1&type=value2&name=value3&type=value4...` but this code should be able to handle any query string passed to it) and create an object from it.

I have nearly completed a function that does this.  However, my logic is a bit off inside that last for loop. If someone could please point out where I've gone wrong I'd really appreciate it!

First I grab the query string using jQuery's `$.get` function:

```
$.get("xmlreader.php", function(data) { 

    var queryParams = [];

    var qString = data;

    // test qString for & at the end
    var last = qString.lastIndexOf("&");
    if(last == qString.length - 1) {
        // then there is a & to remove
        qString = qString.substring(0,qString.length-1);
    }

    getParamObj(qString);

});
```

(I know it's funky that I remove the last & here in my JavaScript but I don't want to focus on that here at all.)

Then I call `getParamObject(qString);` to build the actual collection object:

```
function getParamObj(parameterString) {

var qString = parameterString;
var parameters = qString.split("&");
parameters[0] = parameters[0].substring(1);

var paramObject = new Object();

for(var index = 0; index < parameters.length; ++index) {
    var equalsPos = parameters[index].indexOf("=");
    var key = parameters[index].substring(0,equalsPos);

    var stringLength = parameters[index].length;

    var value = parameters[index].substring(equalsPos + 1, stringLength);

    if(!paramObject[key]) {
        console.log("paramObject[key] = " + paramObject[key]);
        paramObject[key] = value;
        if(paramObject[key] instanceof Array ) {
            console.log("instance of array");
            paramObject[key].push(value);
        }  else {
            var newArray = [];
            var existingValue = paramObject[key];
            console.log("existing value: " + existingValue);
            console.log("value: " + value);
            newArray.push(existingValue);
            newArray.push(value);
            paramObject[key] = newArray;
        }   

    }

}
```

The function is working -almost- correctly. A couple things are wrong when I test it:  in the last conditional existingValue and value are the same. There may be other issues as well but I think that's the primary one.

I've seen approaches that use regular expressions but I DON'T want to take that route here.

Note:     I've answered my own question LOL... stack won't let me comment this because I'm not cool enough yet at just 58 rep :)

```
[code]
if(!paramObject[key]) {
    console.log("paramObject[key] = " + paramObject[key]);
    paramObject[key] = value; 
    console.log("paramObject[key] = value = " + value + paramObject[key]);
    console.log(paramObject[key]);
    }
    else if(paramObject[key] instanceof Array ) {
    paramObject[key].push(value);
    console.log("value if arra" + value);
    }  else {
    var newArray = [];
    var existingValue = paramObject[key];
    console.log("existing value: " + existingValue);
    console.log("value: " + value);
    newArray.push(existingValue);
    newArray.push(value);
    paramObject[key] = newArray;
    }
[/code]
```

Comment: Well, with `paramObject[key] = value;` and `var existingValue = paramObject[key];` you're basically doing `var existingValue = value` aren't you?

Comment: I have solved my own problem LOL...

Comment: Thank you -- sorry, didn't mean to just say 'I solved it'... stack wouldn't let me post the answer here.  I added it as a note to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Although you say you don't want a regex-based implementation, I thought it would be helpful to show what it can look like:

```
params = {}
queryString.replace(/([^&=]+)=([^&=]*)/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
    (params[$1] = params[$1] || []).push($2);
});
// that's basically all about this
```

(Doesn't answer the question, hence CW).